# Is there a way to make two classes to use the same generic?

Tags: java, generics, static, inner-classes

This code is illegal because Bar cannot use the generic T since it belongs to Foo, and Bar is static. :(

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public interface Bar {
        public void bar(T t);
    }

    void foo(T t, Bar bar);
}
```

My question is, is there a reasonable workaround to this problem? I really need Foo and Bar to use the same generic type since Bar is a listener class for Foo and needs to return the same type. Of course I could use two generics (e.g. `Bar<P>`) and always assign the same type to T and P, but that is funky and error prone. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Generic type parameters only apply to instances, not static members or  types.

Comment: It seems to me that the place to force two instances to use the same type parameter(s) is when they are used together. Do you have an example use case (with code)?

Comment: Doesn't there need to be some class inheriting Foo or Bar to use either of them? Also, would it help to make Bar of a specific type as well: `public interface Bar<T>`

Comment: @TedHopp I don't have an example, but I can explain: Bar is a listener class for Foo. Callers will instantiate an instance of Foo, Bar and T, and call foo(T,Bar). foo() will perform some action on T, then return the results to the caller by calling Bar.bar(T). That's why I need Foo and Bar to use the same generic type.

Comment: @BarryFruitman see below. interfaces are always `static`, and thus it does not have access to the type `T` of the parent. You need to make that an interface `Foo.Bar<T>` (or short: `Bar<T>`) instead of `Foo<T>.Bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to make `Bar` generic:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public interface Bar<T> {
        public void bar(T t);
    }
    ...
}
```

Or, if you want to call the type parameter something different:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public interface Bar<U> {
        public void bar(U t);
    }
    ...
}
```

There's really nothing error-prone about it.  If you need a method to, say, register a listener, it would look like:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public interface Bar<U> {
        public void bar(U t);
    }

    public void addListener(Bar<T> listener);
}
```

This would ensure that, if you add a listener to an instance of something that implements `Foo<T>`, then the listener must be something that implements `Bar<T>` with the same generic parameter (if you don't use raw types).

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! It forces Foo and Bar to use the same generic type (via addListener()) without violating its static-ness. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with the nested interface?  Promote that to the top level, and then compose it into the Foo class.

Bar.java

```
public interface Bar<T> {
    void bar(T t);
}
```

Foo.java

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private Bar<T> bar;

    void foo(T t) {

    }

    void bar(T t) {
        this.bar.bar(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use interfaces for testing purposes (i.e. mock objects).

Comment: It's still an interface, it's just not a *nested* interface, but as @ajb's answer demonstrates, the effect is really the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a non-static interface.

For *classes* you can have the desired behavior:

```
class A<T> {
  class B {
    void test(T works) { }
  }
}
```

for interfaces, you will need to use

```
interface A<T> {
  interface B<T> {
    void test(T works) { }
  }
}
```

which is essentially the same as:

```
interface A<T> {
}

interface B<T> {
  void test(T works) { }
}
```

Essentially, **interfaces are always `static`**, and **`static` classes (and interfaces) do not inherit the parents generics**, because it violates the concept of being `static`...